# Why is $\frac{d}{dx} e^y = e^y \frac{dy}{dx}$?

Tags: calculus

My calculus is very basic.

I understand that: $\frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x$

But why is: $\frac{d}{dx} e^y = e^y \frac{dy}{dx}$ ?

I can't seem to find an explanation anywhere.

Comment: Have you heard about the chain rule?

Comment: What you "understand" is wrong.  The "why is" one you ask about is the chain rule.

Comment: Your first equation is wrong: it should say $\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$.

Comment: @Kantura That is the product rule. The chain rule is for a function of a function.

Comment: Loosely speaking, you can think of $\frac{d}{dx}e^y= \frac{dy}{dx}  \frac{d}{dy} e^y$

Comment: @A.Goodier Oh , thanks. I'm looking into it now.

Comment: @Arthur You were the first to direct me to the chain rule which solved my problem. If you write it as an answer I'll give it to you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the Chain Rule?

First differentiate $e^y$ with respect to $y$ and then multiply the result with the derivative of $y$ with respect to new variable $x$. Here $y= y(x)$ that is written as $y$ for short and $y(x)$ is implied.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , the answer lay in the chain rule which I just learned.

$\frac{d}{dx} e^y=A$

Let: $u=e^y$

So: $\frac{du}{dx}=A$

$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{du}{dy} \frac{dy}{dx}=e^y \frac{dy}{dx}$